# How to redirect to another component in a function?

Tags: reactjs

In my app.tsx I have this structure with react-router-dom:

```
<BrowserRouter>
                <Switch>
                    <Route path={"/login"} component={Login}/>
                    <Route path={"/home"} component={HomeScreen}/>
                    <Route path={"/user"} component={UserMenu}/>
                    <Route path={"/profile"} component={ProfileScreen}/>

                    {<Redirect to={"/login"}/>}

                </Switch>
            </BrowserRouter>
```

And within each component I want a function that allows me to move between them, for example, I have tried this.props.history.push () but it doesn't work for me, any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using functional components you can use useHistory.

```
import React from 'react';
import { useHistory } from 'react-router-dom';

const Hello = () => {
  const history = useHistory();
  const handleClick = () => history.push('/route');
  
  return (
    <button type="button" onClick={handleClick}>
      Navigate
    </button>
  );
};
```

If you are using class components you can use withRouter:

```
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom'

class Hello extends React.Component {
  handleClick = (user) => {
      this.props.history.push('/route')
  }
  render() {
    return (
       <button type="button" onClick={this.handleClick}>
         Navigate
       </button>
    )
  }
}

export default withRouter(Hello)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I don't' use functional component, i use class component, you know how can i do it with class component?

Comment: try with Redirect component: render() { return if (...) <Redirect to='/route' /> }

Comment: Look my edit, please, I want a function that was assigned a button click and takes me to another component.

Comment: You can use this.props.history.push('/home') but in combination with withRouter.

Answer (score -1):

How are you trying to run the props.history.push? Because you should be able to write it like props.history.push("home") to redirect to your home component.